# React, display styled text (from a variable) inside div

Tags: reactjs

I need to display styled text inside  div.
When doing it hard coded it works, but when using the variable value the style tags are not taking affect.

I tried this way but it didn't help:

```
<div contentEditable={true} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: element.Display }} 
                             style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}>
                            {/*{element.Display}*/}
                            {/*numOf(from(SHOPDB.DB2ADMIN.CLIENT), SHOPDB.DB2ADMIN.CLIENT.<span style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFF00'}}>LAST_NAME</span> = SHOPDB.DB2ADMIN.CLIENT.LAST_NAME) = 1*/}
                        </div>
```

References:

[Display edited/styled text - react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60434984/display-edited-styled-text-react)

[Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs/27958683)

Comment: can you give an example of what value `element.Display` variable will hold?

Comment: its inside... in a comment! numOf(from(SHOPDB.DB2ADMIN.CLIENT).....

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're wanting the styling `{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: "lightgray" }` to apply to the `<div>` that encloses the html content returned by `DOMPurify.sanitize(element.Display)` ?

Comment: yes, that's the case

Comment: Does this achieve what you require? https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-heisenberg-ngz59

Comment: Yes, I forked your sandbox and used my html and I can see that it's not taking affect! so the problem is with the styled span that I'm using! cause bold is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cannon-bpyww

Comment: I managed this way: <span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>LAST_NAME</span>, I was using the style of react first with {{}}. Thanks a lot

Comment: @M_Z, Are you trying to achieve like this?? https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-firefly-9klel